# Facebook DIVS - profile page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to know how to make these facebook divas, while one eternally scrolls the other only to the end of itself. However, both roll up, the first[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGm1Z.png) fixing at its start.

Comment: Look at position:sticky or javascripts. Question seeking code are being closed. Add details and codes of your attempts to demonstrate a coding issue. You can edit your question with the snippet button and set a demonstration of your issue. Welcome on SO anyway ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using CSS's `position: sticky` you can achieve this effect.

```css
main {
  height: 2000px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

aside {
  flex: none;
  width: 170px;
  background: tomato;
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
  height: 200px;
}
article {
  flex: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(163,122,255,1) 0%, rgba(179,255,0,1) 100%);
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
 <h1>Header</h1>
</header>
<main>
  <aside>
    I'm sticky!
  </aside>
  <article>Main content</article>
</main>
```